# What is the difference in matching between Pattern.compile("\\\"") and Pattern.compile("\"") in Java?

Tags: java, escaping, pattern-matching

Both seem to match a double quote.

I know that `\*` matches the character `*` in regex, (http://www.digitalamit.com/article/regular_expression/2.phtml)

As `*` is a special character, backslash is used to escape it for regex.

But double quote is not a special character for regex. Then why is the backslash needed before a double quote.

In my company code base, they use `Pattern.compile("\\\"")`

Comment: There is no difference. Some people like escaping all "special" (non-word) chars in the pattern.

Comment: You can use the extra escape if you want to make it clear you don't expect it to be used as a special character (otherwise the reader needs to know this)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why is there no difference ?

Comment: Because a ``\"`` pattern matches the same `"` symbol as the `"` pattern does.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, I think then backslash is not needed before double quote, it works without the backslash in most cases:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("^\"$").asPredicate().test("\""));
```

result is true

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("^\\\"$").asPredicate().test("\""));
```

result is true

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("^\\\"$").asPredicate().test("\\\""));
```

result is false. So if you want to match \" you need to put double backslash to your regexp:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("^\\\\\"$").asPredicate().test("\\\""));
```

result is true.

If you build a regexp string it it needed to add backslash before each double quote, unless you cannot match a backslash + double quote.